# Padding on both sides on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

On my [site](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/), the items under `home-boxes` class on the mobile phone appear to have extra padding on the left. How can I avoid it?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row space" >

        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
            <a href="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/why-we-are-needed/">
            <img class="center-block" src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/11.jpg">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="home-boxes">
            <h3>Why we are needed</h3>
            <p>More than half of Karachi’s population lives in low-resource densely-packed neighborhoods, where there are few or no qualified doctors conveniently located. Pollution is high, and diseases are rampant.</p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 ">
            <a href="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/emergency-care-2/">
            <img class="center-block"  src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/21.jpg">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="home-boxes" >
            <h3>Emergency Care</h3>
            <p>During the floods of 2010, CNN correspondent Dr. Sanjay Gupta did a news segment on the dilapidated children’s emergency room (ER) at Civil Hospital, Karachi.</p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <a href="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/primary-care-2/">
            <img class="center-block"  src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/3.jpg">
            <div class="col-xs-12" id="home-boxes">
            <h3>Primary Care</h3>
            <p>ChildLife Foundation initiated a partnership with SINA Trust in 2012 under the leadership of their common trustee, Dr. Naseeruddin Mahmood. Since 1998, SINA has been operating primary care clinics in low-income.</p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <a href="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/preventive-care/">
            <img class="center-block"  src="http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/5.jpg">
            <div  class="col-xs-12" id="home-boxes">
            <h3>Preventive Care</h3>
            <p>394,000 children in Pakistan die before their fifth birthdays. 122,000 of them did not make it past their first year of life. As a result, Pakistan has the third highest mortality rate in the world, primarily because of preventable... </p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*
Theme Name: Child Life Foundation
Theme URI: http://underscores.me/
Author: Fahad Uddin
Author URI: http://underscores.me/
Description: Inspurate has created a website template for Child Life Foundation
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: child-life-foundation
Tags:

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.

Child Life Foundation is based on Underscores http://underscores.me/, (C) 2012-2015 Automattic, Inc.
Underscores is distributed under the terms of the GNU GPL v2 or later.

Normalizing styles have been helped along thanks to the fine work of
Nicolas Gallagher and Jonathan Neal http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/
*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
>>> TABLE OF CONTENTS:
----------------------------------------------------------------
# Normalize
# Typography
# Elements
# Forms
# Navigation
    ## Links
    ## Menus
# Accessibility
# Alignments
# Clearings
# Widgets
# Content
    ## Posts and pages
    ## Asides
    ## Comments
# Infinite scroll
# Media
    ## Captions
    ## Galleries
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Normalize
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:     100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
    display: block;
}

audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}

[hidden],
template {
    display: none;
}

a {
    background-color: transparent;
    color:#dbff98;
}

a:active,
a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}

abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b,
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

dfn {
    font-style: italic;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}

mark {
    background: #ff0;
    color: #000;
}

small {
    font-size: 80%;
}

sub,
sup {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
    top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
    bottom: -0.25em;
}

img {
    border: 0;
}

svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}

figure {
    margin: 1em 40px;
}

hr {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}

pre {
    overflow: auto;
}

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
    font-family: monospace, monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

button {
    overflow: visible;
}

button,
select {
    text-transform: none;
}

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

input {
    line-height: normal;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    height: auto;
}

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

legend {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
}

optgroup {
    font-weight: bold;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
    padding: 0;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Typography
--------------------------------------------------------------*/


body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    color: #404040;
/*  font-family: sans-serif;
*/
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    clear: both;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#9bbd1b;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

dfn,
cite,
em,
i {
    font-style: italic;
}

blockquote {
    margin: 0 1.5em;
}

address {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

pre {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 1.6em;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1.6em;
}

code,
kbd,
tt,
var {
    font-family: Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
}

abbr,
acronym {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
    cursor: help;
}

mark,
ins {
    background: #fff9c0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

big {
    font-size: 125%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Elements
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after { /* Inherit box-sizing to make it easier to change the property for components that leverage other behavior; see http://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/ */
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    background: #fff; /* Fallback for when there is no custom background color defined. */
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: "";
}

blockquote,
q {
    quotes: "" "";
}

hr {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

ul,
ol {
    /* margin: 0 0 1.5em 3em; */
    /* margin: 0 0 1.5em 3em; */
    /* margin: 0 0 1.5em -2em; */
}

ul {
    list-style: disc;
}

ol {
    list-style: decimal;
}

li > ul,
li > ol {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
    margin: 0 1.5em 1.5em;
}

img {
    height: auto; /* Make sure images are scaled correctly. */
    max-width: 100%; /* Adhere to container width. */
}

table {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Forms
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background: #9bbd1b;
    /* box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 15px 17px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 -5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); */
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: .6em 1em .4em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

button:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover {
    border-color: #ccc #bbb #aaa;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), inset 0 15px 17px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), inset 0 -5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

button:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
button:active,
input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="reset"]:active,
input[type="submit"]:active {
    border-color: #aaa #bbb #bbb;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"],
textarea {
    color: #666;
    border: 0px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
textarea:focus {
    color: #111;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
    padding: 3px;
}

textarea {
    padding-left: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Links
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
a {
    color: #dbff98;
}
/*
a:visited {
    color: purple;
}
*/
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
    outline: 0;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Menus
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5em;
    left: -999em;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
    top: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
    width: 200px;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li {

}

.main-navigation li:hover > a,
.main-navigation li.focus > a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a,
.main-navigation ul ul .focus > a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul a:hover,
.main-navigation ul ul a.focus {
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
    left: auto;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul ul li.focus > ul {
    left: 100%;
}

.main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a {
}


/* Small menu. */
.menu-toggle,
.main-navigation.toggled ul {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .main-navigation ul {
        display: block;
    }
}

.site-main .comment-navigation,
.site-main .posts-navigation,
.site-main .post-navigation {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-previous,
.posts-navigation .nav-previous,
.post-navigation .nav-previous {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-next,
.posts-navigation .nav-next,
.post-navigation .nav-next {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Accessibility
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Text meant only for screen readers. */
.screen-reader-text {
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.screen-reader-text:focus {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    clip: auto !important;
    color: #21759b;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    left: 5px;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 15px 23px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 5px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 100000; /* Above WP toolbar. */
}

/* Do not show the outline on the skip link target. */
#content[tabindex="-1"]:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Alignments
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.alignleft {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.alignright {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.aligncenter {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Clearings
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.clear:before,
.clear:after,
.entry-content:before,
.entry-content:after,
.comment-content:before,
.comment-content:after,
.site-header:before,
.site-header:after,
.site-content:before,
.site-content:after,
.site-footer:before,
.site-footer:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.clear:after,
.entry-content:after,
.comment-content:after,
.site-header:after,
.site-content:after,
.site-footer:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Widgets
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.widget {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

/* Make sure select elements fit in widgets. */
.widget select {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Content
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Posts and pages
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.sticky {
    display: block;
}

.hentry {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

.byline,
.updated:not(.published) {
    display: none;
}

.single .byline,
.group-blog .byline {
    display: inline;
}

.page-content,
.entry-content,
.entry-summary {
    margin: 1.5em 0 0;
}

.page-links {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Asides
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.blog .format-aside .entry-title,
.archive .format-aside .entry-title {
    display: none;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Comments
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.comment-content a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.bypostauthor {
    display: block;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Infinite scroll
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Globally hidden elements when Infinite Scroll is supported and in use. */
.infinite-scroll .posts-navigation, /* Older / Newer Posts Navigation (always hidden) */
.infinite-scroll.neverending .site-footer { /* Theme Footer (when set to scrolling) */
    display: none;
}

/* When Infinite Scroll has reached its end we need to re-display elements that were hidden (via .neverending) before. */
.infinity-end.neverending .site-footer {
    display: block;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Media
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.page-content .wp-smiley,
.entry-content .wp-smiley,
.comment-content .wp-smiley {
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Make sure embeds and iframes fit their containers. */
embed,
iframe,
object {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Captions
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.wp-caption {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.wp-caption img[class*="wp-image-"] {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
    margin: 0.8075em 0;
}

.wp-caption-text {
    text-align: center;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Galleries
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.gallery {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.gallery-item {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

.gallery-columns-2 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 50%;
}

.gallery-columns-3 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 33.33%;
}

.gallery-columns-4 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 25%;
}

.gallery-columns-5 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 20%;
}

.gallery-columns-6 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 16.66%;
}

.gallery-columns-7 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 14.28%;
}

.gallery-columns-8 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 12.5%;
}

.gallery-columns-9 .gallery-item {
    max-width: 11.11%;
}

.gallery-caption {
    display: block;
}
.site{ 
    border-top: 10px solid #9bbd1b;
}
.line{ 
    border-top: 5px solid #9bbd1b;
}

.site-header{
        background-color:#ffffde;
}
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.nav>li{
     display: inline-block !important;
     padding: 0 0 0 34px;
     width: 160px;
}       
    .footerspace{
    margin-top:65px;
    }

}

.nav>li a{
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#484848;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: HelveticaRounded;

}
.nav > li > a:hover{

    background-color:#9bbd1b !important;
    color:#FFF;
}


.nav li ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}


.nav li li a{
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: HelveticaRounded;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-left:-10px;
    width: 160px;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px;
    background-color:#9bbd1b !important;
}


    .search{
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
    }


@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    /*
    .navbar{
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    */
    .search{
        margin-top: 100px; /* 10 pixel extra than navbar because in navbar there is a padding-top of 10 pixel on text. */
    }
    .donate{
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    .space{
        margin: 50px 0;
    }
    .logo{
        margin-top: 13px;
    }

}
h3{
    font-size:19px;
}

.navbar{
    float:right;

}

.footerwidget{
    font-size:14px; color:#989898; margin-top:33px;
}

.footerheading h2{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {


    .nav {
        margin-top:50px;
    }

    .footertext, .footertext a{
        text-align:center;

    }

}

.green{
    background-color:#8ab51e;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.green h3{
    color:#FFF;
}
.navbar{
        margin-top: -7px;
    margin-bottom: -12px;
}
.btn{
    background-color:#9bbd1b;
}
.white, .white a {
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-danger:hover{
        background-color: #000000;
}
.greenIcon, .greenIcon a {
  color: #9bbd1b;
}
.btn-white {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.btn-white:hover {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.input-group-btn:last-child>.btn, .input-group-btn:last-child>.btn-group{
    background-color: #9bbd1b !important;
    border: 1px solid #9bbd1b !important;
}

.primary-menu{
    font-family: HelveticaRounded;
}

#home-boxes{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;     border-style: solid;
    border-top: solid #8ab51e; height: 265px;
    color:#404040;
}
#home-boxes:hover{
    background-color:#8ab51e;
    color:#FFF;
}
#home-boxes:hover h3{
    background-color:#8ab51e;
    color:#FFF;
}
#
.donate_bg{
        background-image: url("http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/donate_image.png");
}
.donate_bg h3{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: HelveticaRounded;
}

.footertext, .footertext a{
        color:#989898;
        font-size:16px;
        margin-top:30px;
}
.navbar .nav>li>a:focus, .navbar .nav>li>a:hover{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.input-group .form-control, .input-group-addon, .input-group-btn{
    height: 31px;
}
#secondary{
        background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.ubermenu-skin-grey-white .ubermenu-submenu, .ubermenu-skin-grey-white .ubermenu-submenu .ubermenu-target{
    color:#FFF !important;  
}
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
#main{
    margin-top:50px;
}

#main a{
    color:#9bbd1b;
}

#secondary a{
        color:#808080;
}

#secondary li{
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    list-style-type: 009B;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#secondary li:before {
        content: "\00BB \0020";
         }

         #secondary ul  {
        list-style:none;
         }





.col-md-9.donate .col-md-3 > a {
    background: #D20059 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    font-family: HelveticaRounded;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.col-md-9.donate .col-md-3 > a > img
{
    width: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:300px) and (max-width: 992px) {
.col-md-9.donate .col-md-3 > a {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    height:31px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:992px){
    .inner-sidebar{
            display:none;
    }
}

.mobile{
        margin: 0;
}

html, body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#flexslider-title{
    display:none;
}
#comment{
    border: 1px solid #174946;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look with the developer tools of your browser.

Assuming that we're looking at the same elements, the extra 15px on the left side is due to this on the line 732 of `bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css`:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .row, .thumbnails {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

which resets the negative margin on the left side but not on the right side. You could counter that with setting it back to -15px on `.row`:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .row {
        margin-left: -15px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution. For some reason, it doesn't work.

Comment: @FahadUddin At least I seem to be missing some braces there. Make sure to include those, I've fixed the answer. Still having the same issue?

Comment: @FahadUddin I tested this on your site, and at least adding `.row { margin-left: -15px }` works for me. You'll want to include the media query of course.

Answer (score -1):

Just had a look at your site. It seams the the Bootstrap css file is adding 20px padding to left and right side of the Body element using a @media query after 767px.

All you need to do is override this in your own css file. Like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

The !important extensions will do as they say. It will override the styling no matter what the css hierarchy is. I'm putting these in to be safe as Bootstrap may override your custom css without !important extensions. Try the code above without !important extensions and see if it works also.

Comment: If the padding on `body` is identical on both sides, then how could that bring about a different number on the left and the right side? And then how does making an identical change on both sides help the difference?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about my friend. If you look at his site, bootstrap is adding padding-left and padding-right. Theyre both set to 20px under screen width of 767px. Simply disabling this with the code above works fine. I dont really know what you're talking about tbh.  Also, please consider up voting my answer. Trying to get some reputation on here and I think my answer is very decent and helpful.

Comment: Yes, it is adding that 20px padding to both sides, and disabling that takes 20px of the padding away from both sides. But after that there's still more whitespace on the left side compared to the right side, no?

Comment: Btw, @Roope, You're answer is incorrect. You should never counter margin or padding issues by using negative values. Is not good for the long run of the site, can make templating and generally managing a site very troublesome indeed.

Comment: I'm not countering with negative values in the normal sense. That would be stupid, you are correct, just postponing the problem. But rather it happens to be what Bootstrap does, there are plenty of negative -15px and -30px margins that are a central part of the layout structuring.

Comment: I see what you mean but that isnt the question and it isnt to do with margins either. The layout seems fine, it seems that theres an element overflowing the page and causing what appears to be white space. If you scroll left, you'll see that everything is centered and in fact that there is an element that is overflowing. That wasn't his question though.

Comment: Okay, can you name that element? I'd take a look.

Comment: I don't really have the time to look tbh, in my experience, it's usually a h1 tag or something like that.